# How to make slider smooth and continuous while registering only discrete values?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, frontend

The only valid values for my slider are the integers 1 to 10. However, as the user drags the thumb and slides the slider, it should appear continuous and smooth.

How can this be done?

Comment: Does the value have to update as the slider is moved or can you wait for the user to stop the sliding interaction before checking the new value?

Comment: the values should update live and not just when the user releases the thumb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<input>` range slider locks movement of the thumb to increments of it's `step` attribute. By default it's set to 1. So if you have a range of 1 to 10, the slider's width gets subdivided into 10 sections.

What you can do is set the step attribute to e.g. `0.01` - which will subdivide your slider into 1000 sections - and convert the floating point value the slider returns to a whole number.

For example:

```js
document.getElementById("range").oninput= (e)=>{
  document.getElementById("val").innerText=parseInt(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
  <input id="range" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0" step="0.01">
  <span id="val"></span>
```